# Htaccess same file double redirect forwarding

Tags: .htaccess, file, redirect, double, forward

I'm having trouble finding if and how can one make a forwarding redirect through htaccess from a file on my server to a specific url and then auto redirect it again to another url.
I need something like example.php ori example.jpg when it's called to redirect to http://example.com/example2.php and then to be redirected again to http://example.com/example3.jpg. Also can the delay between redirects be controlled somehow? Is it possible?

Comment: you want to redirect example.php to example2.php then example2.php to example3.php or again the same example.php to example3.php?

Comment: I need example.php to be first redirected to URL then example.php to be redirected to example2.php. The same file first redirect to a link then to another file. Sorry for the unclarity.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to write a chain redirection from a file to url and back to a file. Any idea on that?